# Upload Pdf file into database

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I have to upload all files into my database. My database is available at server. For now I am trying to upload pdf files but I am unable to upload 
it. I tried many codes from google also but till now non of those worked for me. How can I upload pdf files into my database?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit1"]))
 {

echo $filename = basename($_FILES['healthfile']['name']);
$newname = $folder_path . $filename;

$FileType = pathinfo($newname,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if($FileType == "pdf")
{
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['healthfile']['tmp_name'], $newname))
{

$filesql = "INSERT INTO user(pdf) VALUES('$filename') WHERE id='$id'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $filesql);
if (isset($query))
{
echo 'File Uploaded';
} else
{
 echo 'Something went Wrong';
 }
 }
 else
 {

 echo "<p>Upload Failed.</p>";
 }


}
else
{
echo "<p>Class notes must be uploaded in PDF format.</p>";
}

}
?>
```

Comment: post your html to?

Comment: And why you tag `css` tag here, do you think the issue is related to css ?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: where is `$id` set?

Comment: @Jeff my pdf file is not going into my database.

Comment: This link will help, http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-insert-files-into-a-MySQL-database-using-PHP.php

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve with that sql query?  are you looking to insert a new row (in which case, what purpose does the id clause serve?) or update an existing row (in which case, it should be an UPDATE query)?

Comment: @flauntster Iam not updating anything. I just want add particular pdf file to a particular  id. So I have to use insert query.

Comment: @sanamiraj  so you're attempting to insert a row and set the id via your query? and you're not using an auto-incrementing index for id column?

Comment: If that is your complete code in the question, $id is never set anywhere so the query will fail.

Comment: Its not my complete code. @flauntster

Comment: ok, so assuming you have set $id somewhere earlier in the script, and you are attempting to insert a row into user table which has id & pdf columns, you could change the query to:  INSERT INTO user(id,pdf) VALUES('$id', '$filename')

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do an UPDATE and not an INSERT INTO if $id is defined :

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST["submit1"]))
 {

echo $filename = basename($_FILES['healthfile']['name']);
$newname = $folder_path . $filename;

$FileType = pathinfo($newname,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if($FileType == "pdf")
{
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['healthfile']['tmp_name'], $newname))
{

$filesql = "UPDATE user SET pdf ='$filename' WHERE id='$id'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $filesql);
if (isset($query))
{
echo 'File Uploaded';
} else
{
 echo 'Something went Wrong';
 }
 }
 else
 {

 echo "<p>Upload Failed.</p>";
 }


}
else
{
echo "<p>Class notes must be uploaded in PDF format.</p>";
}

}
?>
```